# Core data - remove entity if no foreign keys

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using `Core Data` in my app and have some entities that have many-to-many relationships. Is there a way to configure the relationships in such way that all entities that don't have at least one entry in some cross-reference table get removed?

Simplified entities:

```
User:
 - songs
 - albums

Song
 - users

Album
 - users
```

For example, when I remove all users from some `album`, I want that `album` to get removed. I know this can be done by checking the number of remaining users, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: The "right" way would be to add intermediate entities, something like UserSong and UserAlbum to get rid of the many-many relationships.  Then it's a lot easier to determine which albums have no users, etc.  If you google something like "relational database many-many relationship", you'll find some good information on database conventions.

Comment: By examining .sqlite file generated by app, I saw that Core Data framework already does that (creates cross-reference tables). Intermediate entities are a little too much, considering that I can just iterate data and check size of related arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the delete rule of the relationships in both directions to "Cascade" in the model editor. Core Data should then delete the corresponding entity instances automatically.

You should **not** follow any advice recommending intermediate "join" tables. This is bad and redundant practice within the Core Data framework and only necessary if you need to store additional information about each relationship itself.

Comment: Let's say all `songs` get removed from `user` but it still has some `albums`, will this delete the `user` instance?

Comment: No. As long as there are valid relationships, the user should not be deleted. Best way is to try it out ;-).